# Access Prestashop cookies from JavaScript

Tags: cookies, prestashop

Any method to read Prestashop Cookies from Javascript ?

```
Context::getContext()->cookie
```

I try with

```
document.cookie
```

But can't acces to the prestashop Cookies, any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Cookie content in PHP and set into a template as JS variable.

You assign with PHP

```
$context->smarty->assign('yourData', $dataFromCookie);
```

and receive in your template file:

```
{addJsDef name=yourDataVar}{$yourData}{/addJsDef}
```